# Can self-destroying std::stop_callback objects destroy themselves during construction?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, destructor

As said on cppreference.com([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_callback/%7Estop_callback)), `std::stop_callback` object is allowed to destroy itself inside its callback function. So the code below should be fine.

```cpp
template <typename F>
void doAfterStop(std::stop_token && st, F f)
{
    struct ControlBlock
    {
        F f;
        struct Helper
        {
            ControlBlock * cb;
            void operator()()
            {
                cb->f();
                delete cb;
            }
        };
        std::stop_callback<Helper> sc;
        ControlBlock(std::stop_token && st, F f)
            : f{ f }
            , sc{ std::move(st), Helper{this} }
        {}
    };
    new ControlBlock{ std::move(st), f };
}

int main()
{
    std::stop_source ss;
    //ss.request_stop();//?
    doAfterStop(ss.get_token(), []{ std::puts("Byebye, world!"); });
    ss.request_stop();
    return 0;
}
```

But what if I put the `ss.request_stop();` line before the `doAfterStop(...);` line?

The `std::stop_callback`'s destructor would be called right inside its own constructor. So does `ControlBlock`. Is it still safe?

Does it exhibit undefined behavior? If yes, what exactly in the standard forbids this?

Comment: Its a bit weird as the end of the object's lifetime happens before the end of the constructor, but I don't see any problematic operations in the constructor after the end of the lifetime (since sc is the last member, and thus the last to be constructed, and the constructor body is empty).

Comment: From the library perspective, the UB is prolly due to not explicitly allowed «recursive» call, where «recursive», per some LWG issue, also includes calling a method during some other method call on the same object. From the Core language perspective, it is a bit tricky :/

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Do you mean this one: [Issue 2414](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2414)? From the spirit of their discussion, I feel they tend to forbid this kind of recursion for the use of the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

- The operand of an delete-expression **must** be a constructed object.
  For the object to be considered constructed its initialization must have completed.
  In your case this means that the constructor must have finished executing.
  => `delete this;` directly within a constructor (or within one of the functions that are called as part of your objects construction) will [almost] always be undefined behavior.
- If you want a self-destroying `std::stop_callback` you need to either:

  - (a) handle the edge-case that the construction of the `std::stop_callback` might directly invoke the callback and delay the destruction until construction has completed.
  - (b) make sure you register all your self-destroying `std::stop_callback`s before calling [`std::stop_source::request_stop()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_source/request_stop)
- Note that you still have an unhandled edge-case:
  There is no guarantee that a stop will be requested at all.
  In case no stop is issued on your `std::stop_source` your `ControlBlock` will simply get leaked.
  Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GTe1cqWxh)

---

### 1. Legalese Stuff

Assuming the case where you call `std::stop_source::request_stop()` before `doAfterStop(...)`, e.g.:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::stop_source ss;
    ss.request_stop();
    doAfterStop(ss.get_token(), []{ std::puts("Byebye, world!"); });
    return 0;
}
```

This will basically invoke the `Helper::operator()` as part of `std::stop_callback`'s constructor, so a simplified example of this case could be:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3x8zfdh9x)

```cpp
struct Bar {
    Bar() { delete this; }
    ~Bar() { }
};

int main() {
    new Bar();
}
```

=> Is it legal to delete an object as part of its constructor?

The lifetime of an object starts only **after** its initialization is complete:

> [6.7.3 Lifetime [basic.life]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#1) (emphasis mine)
> <sup>(1)</sup> [...] The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
> <sup>(1.1)</sup> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
> <sup>(1.2)</sup> - **its initialization (if any) is complete** (including vacuous initialization) ([[dcl.init]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init))

In case of your `ControlBlock` class the initialization performed will be [*direct-initialization*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#general-15.2), which involves calling your constructor:

> [9.4.1 General [dcl.init.general]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#general-16.6.2.1) (emphasis mine)
> <sup>(16.6.2)</sup> [...] If the initialization is direct-initialization, [...], constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated, and the best one is chosen through overload resolution.
> Then:
> <sup>(16.6.2.1)</sup> If overload resolution is successful, **the selected constructor is called to initialize the object**, with the initializer expression or expression-list as its argument(s).

So while your constructor is running the object is not yet within its lifetime, because initialization is not yet completed.

So attempting to perform a [delete-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) from within the constructor with `this` as operand would violate *6.7.3 Lifetime (6)*:

> [6.7.3 Lifetime [basic.life]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#6.1) (emphasis mine)
> <sup>(6)</sup> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated [...], any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways. [...]
> **The program has undefined behavior if:**
> <sup>(6.1)</sup> the object will be or was of a class type with a non-trivial destructor and **the pointer is used as the operand of a [*delete-expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.delete#nt:delete-expression)**

<sup>Note 1: `std::stop_callback` has a user-defined destructor, so it is definitely not [trivially destructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor). Your `ControlBlock` has a data member of type `std::stop_callback`, which results in its destructor being non-trivial as well.</sup>
<sup>Note 2: There are some exceptions to 6.7.3 Lifetime (6) for class objects, but none of them permit delete-expressions: [11.9.5 Construction and destruction](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.cdtor)</sup>

So your example would result in undefined behavior, because it attempts to delete an object [with a non-trivial destructor] which is not yet within its lifetime.

---

Alternatively we can also the definition of implicit destructor calls to arrive at the same conclusion:
(Note that **all** ways (including delete-expressions) that result in implicit destructor calls require a **constructed object**)

> [11.4.7 Destructors [class.dtor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.dtor#15) (emphasis mine)
> <sup>(15)</sup> A destructor is invoked implicitly
>
> - <sup>(15.1)</sup> for a **constructed object** with static storage duration at program termination
> - <sup>(15.2)</sup> for a **constructed object** with thread storage duration at thread exit
> - <sup>(15.3)</sup> for a **constructed object** with automatic storage duration when the block in which an object is created exits,
> - <sup>(15.4)</sup> for a **constructed temporary object** when its lifetime ends
>
> [...] A destructor may also be invoked implicitly through use of a [*delete-expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.delete#nt:delete-expression) for a **constructed object** allocated by a [*new-expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.new#nt:new-expression) [...]

The definition of *constructed object* is given by:

> [9.4.1 General [dcl.init.general]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.general#20) (emphasis mine)
> <sup>(20)</sup> An object **whose initialization has completed** is deemed to be **constructed**. [...]

So given that the call to the constructor is part of the initialization of your class, and by virtue of the delete expression being executed within the constructor, the operand can't [yet] be a constructed object. (it only becomes a constructed object once initialization is complete)

=> So your example would result in UB because it violates the precondition of the implicit destructor call, which calls for a *constructed object*.

---

### 2. The compiler check

One neat thing about C++ constant expressions is that we can (ab-)use them to test for undefined behavior.

Most undefined behavior is ill-formed within constant expressions, so compilers **must** produce an compilation error if they encounter such undefined behavior in a context that requires a constant expression.

> [7.7 Constant expressions [expr.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.7) (emphasis mine)
> <sup>(5)</sup> An expression *E* is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of *E*, following the rules of the abstract machine ([[intro.execution]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.execution)), would evaluate one of the following:
> [..]
>
> - <sup>(5.7)</sup> **an operation that would have undefined behavior** as specified in [[intro]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro) through [[cpp]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cpp);

<sup>Note that this includes all types of undefined behavior from sections 4-15 of the [C++ Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/) - the only thing that's not covered by this are the various standard library headers.</sup>

This method of checking is unfortunately not completely foolproof, as it depends on compilers 100% correctly implementing the C++ standard (which is hard). But it can still be a good check to see if a given piece of code is standard-conforming.

Here are the results for gcc 12.3, clang 16.0.0 & msvc 19.35:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/W8v3c54a6)

```cpp
struct Bar {
    constexpr Bar() { delete this; }
    constexpr ~Bar() { }
};

consteval void foo() {
    new Bar();
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

Note that all 3 compilers **reject** this code:

- gcc:

  ```
  error: deallocation of storage that was not previously allocated
  ```
- clang:

  ```
  note: destruction of object that is already being destroyed
  ```
- msvc:

  ```
  note: failure was caused by deallocation of pointer not allocated on the heap
  ```

On the other hand all compilers do accept it if the delete-expression happens after construction has completed:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z1KxMKs74)

```cpp
struct Bar {
    constexpr Bar() { }
    constexpr ~Bar() { }

    constexpr void yeet() {
        delete this; 
    }
};

consteval void foo() {
    (new Bar())->yeet();
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

---

### 3. Potential Fix

One way you can work around this would be to check if the callback got invoked while the constructor was still running.

Note that this checking must be thread-safe, because the callback might get invoked from another thread while we're still in the process of constructing the `ControlBlock`.

Example:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bj8d53oWq)

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <stop_token>

template <class F>
void doAfterStop(std::stop_token const& st, F f) {
    struct ControlBlock {
        enum State {
            // constructor is running
            Constructing = 0,
            // callback has been called while constructor is running
            SyncDestruct = 1,

            // constructor has finished
            Constructed = 2,
            // callback has been called after constructor finished
            DirectDestruct = 3
        };

        struct Helper {
            ControlBlock* cb;

            void operator()() const {
                cb->f();

                int state = cb->state.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel) + 1;
                if(state == State::DirectDestruct) {
                    delete cb;
                }
            }
        };

        // order is important!
        // state and f must be constructed before sc!
        std::atomic<int> state;
        F f;
        std::stop_callback<Helper> sc;
        

        ControlBlock(std::stop_token const& st, F&& f)
            : state{ State::Constructing },
              f{ std::move(f) },
              sc{ st, Helper{this} }
        { }

        void checkDestructImmediately() {
            int expected = State::Constructing;
            bool res = state.compare_exchange_strong(expected, State::Constructed, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
            if(!res) {
                delete this;
            }
        }
    };

    ControlBlock* cb = new ControlBlock{ st, std::move(f) };
    cb->checkDestructImmediately();
}
```

Note that this implementation will still leak the `ControlBlock` in case a stop never gets requested on the `std::stop_source`.

So you always need to request a stop, otherwise `ControlBlock`s might get leaked.

Comment: I agree most of the answer, but I don't think the _6.7.3 Lifetime (6)_ violations apply here. The standard reads :"For an object under construction or destruction, see [class.cdtor]. **Otherwise**, ... . Indirection through such a pointer ... . The program has undefined behavior if: ...". I believe 6.1 through 6.5 belongs to the "Otherwise" and don't apply to objs under construction. If these did apply, the entry 6.2 "the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object" would forbid member function call in ctor, which I believe IS allowed.

Answer (score -2):

By this [request_stop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_source/request_stop), I don't see any call to `std::stop_callback`'s destructor. So the call is safe.

Also, try add this print:

```
auto print = [](const std::stop_source &source) {
    std::printf("stop_source stop_possible = %s, stop_requested = %s\n",
                source.stop_possible() ? "true" : "false",
                source.stop_requested() ? "true" : "false");
};
```

You will get before the call to `ss.request_stop()`:

```
stop_source stop_possible = true, stop_requested = false
```

And after:

```
stop_source stop_possible = true, stop_requested = true
```

Which means you got a flag for all relevant instances.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't see any call to std::stop_callback's destructor"? It is called by the `delete cb;` line. During the destruction of the `ControlBlock` object, its member `std::stop_callback<Helper> sc` is destructed.